# How to show custom alert without adding Jsx tag in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, alert

I want to show a custom alert which is a third party library from axios interceptor after response. But the Interceptors file don't have any UI so how to show my custom alert without adding it in the render method.

```
import AlertPro from "react-native-alert-pro";
// Add a response interceptor

    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
      function (response) {
        // Do something with response data
        return response.data;
      },
      function (error) {
     AlertPro.open();
        // Do something with response error

     //   return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
```

I have tried the above code but not working.

Comment: if you show a AlertPro you must put a render method

Comment: Thank you.Is there any alert except from default Alert to show without adding it in the render method?

Comment: you can use normal alert like  `alert(response.data +"response")`